# How Do I Verify Ubuntu 22.04 ISO Download?

Tags: 22.04, iso

How can I verify a download from Canonical so that I know the download ISO file is legitimate?**

Comment: Every Ubuntu ISO is signed, if you're worried why don't you verify the signature is valid using the GPG key.  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu

Comment: In other words, it is important to check with a checksum program and/or a GPG key. The current versions of Ubuntu use `sha256sum` for the checksum. This kind of checking will also help you identify corruption because of internet transfer errors (which is much more common than fake Linux systems).

Answer (score 1):

On the Ubuntu ISO download page, there is a link "Verify your download". When you click on that link, it displays you the checksum of the official ISO image. You can verify that checksum to make sure your download is genuine.

Comment: Can you give me details of that procedure please?

Comment: @MikeG Click on the link and it displays an explanation how to verify the download. There is also a more extensive tutorial: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

Comment: Thank you very much. The reason I asked is that I am having install issues and the Boot repair said it was 32 bit and I know I downloaded a 64 bit release. How do I mark this as the answer?

Comment: After a couple of days (that is now), there should be a [I think grey] *tick* icon. Click on it, and it will change colour to green, which indicates that you have accepted the answer as the solution.